# vs forms , show hidden form on form load

Tags: c#, winforms

(.net 3.5 compact)
I have a form which is hidden(b) .
When I open my new form(a), i want to display this hidden form(b) that is hidden.

If i create a button on form(a) and on the click event i do a .Show() , it works fine .

if i add the ff to the load event  , the forms does not come to the front and stays hidden.Also tried adding it after InitializeComponent(); but the form does not come to the front.

```
        reg.frmScanner.Show();
```

I have read the minimize trick here , but there is no minimize on mobile device

Comment: Try the BringToFront() method.  Do beware that this is a strong hint that the form was created on a worker thread.  Also matches the usage, a "scanner" tends to generate events on a background thread.  That is not healthy, be sure to use BeginInvoke() so all UI is created on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it to be in the foreground use

```
reg.frmScanner.TopMost = true;
```

Comment: Thanks , works like a charm, i do form.show and the form.TopMost as you suggested and it works !

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of form `reg.frmScanner`. Hide it using  `reg.frmScanner.Hide()`when needed. Show it using `reg.frmScanner.Show()`. 
You will not get desired show/hide results if you use direct calling the form without creating an instance of it.

Comment: I am creating an instance , thats not the problem, form is there , just in the background, need to be in the foreground on another forms load